# Getting all post without blocked users posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm tying to improve my sql. I have 3 tabels called `users`, `posts` and `blocked`. If one user block another user it will add to `blocked` table `from`(blocker id) `to`(blocked id). Then it doesn't show this users posts to each other. I made it with 2 steps. Firsts looks to `blocked` users table with `Select * from 'blocked' where from = :my_id OR to = :my_id`. I save all `ids` in `array`. Then if i will take posts, i'm using `Select * from posts where poster_id NOT IN (array)`. This method works. But i think it will slover if i block more than 1000 people. Any idea how can i do with one sql?

Comment: start learning about joins

Comment: @Dagon Thanks but i now about joins. but problem is that, i get everytime wrong posts or nothing

Comment: post your join, and the db schema